# Settings for easylist and itemize

Tags: itemize, easylist

In the following MWE (I am using Lualatex), I need a way to:

- Decrease vertical spacing between bullets of itemize/easylist so that they match the vertical spacing as that of the lines within ordinary paragraphs.
- Increase number of levels for itemize/easylist
- Increase the indentation for non-bulleted items so that they match the indentation of the bulleted items

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,margin=2.5cm,bindingoffset=0.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{indentfirst} % indent first paragraph after section
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} 
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{6} 

\makeatletter 
\def\toclevel@subsubparagraph{6}
\providecommand\theHsubsubparagraph {\theHsubparagraph.\arabic{subsubparagraph}}
\newcounter {subsubparagraph}[subparagraph]
\renewcommand\thesubsubparagraph {\thesubparagraph.\@arabic\c@subsubparagraph}
\newcommand*\l@subsubparagraph{\@dottedtocline{6}{12em}{6em}}
\newcommand\subsubparagraph{\@startsection{subsubparagraph}{6}{\parindent}%
                                       {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex}%
                                       {-1em}%
                                      {\normalfont\normalsize\itshape}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{noitemsep, topsep=0pt} 
\setlistdepth{9}

\setlist[itemize,1]{label=$\bullet$}
\setlist[itemize,2]{label=$\bullet$}
\setlist[itemize,3]{label=$\bullet$}
\setlist[itemize,4]{label=$\bullet$}
\setlist[itemize,5]{label=$\bullet$}
\setlist[itemize,6]{label=$\bullet$}
\setlist[itemize,7]{label=$\bullet$}
\setlist[itemize,8]{label=$\bullet$}
\setlist[itemize,9]{label=$\bullet$}
\renewlist{itemize}{itemize}{9}

\usepackage[at]{easylist} 

\usepackage[bidi=basic,layout=lists.tabular]{babel}
\babelfont[english]{rm}{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}
\begin{easylist}[itemize]
\ListProperties(Space1=0.1cm, % Level not 1, Space1,  Level 1
                Space1*=0.1cm,% Level 1,     Space1*, Level 1
                Space2=0.15cm,    % Level not 2, Space2,  Level 2
                Space2*=0.1cm, % Level 2,     Space2*, Level 2
                Space3=0.1cm, % Level not 3, Space3,  Level 3
                Space3*=0.1cm, % Level 3,     Space3*, Level 3
                )
@ Such subject is:
@@ rigid-bo:
   @@@ mics: 
   @@@@  bodies:
   @@@@  forces:
    @@@@@ errer:
\end{easylist}
\end{document}
```

[image: Compilation Output]

Comment: What are non-indented items?

Comment: Sorry what I meant was non-bulleted items, not non-indented

Comment: Which items are non-bulleted?

Comment: The text (errer:) is the unbulleted one

Comment: And it should be indented as which  level items?

Comment: I need it to be at level 5, which is not defined in the default settings for easylist and itemize

Comment: Well, you managed to add more levels, what about vertical spacing between each level, is there a way to customize it?

Answer (score 1):

For `easylist`, I do not use it, so I don't know. With `enumitem`, you just have to specify an empty label:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,margin=2.5cm,bindingoffset=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{indentfirst} % indent first paragraph after section
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{6}

\makeatletter
\def\toclevel@subsubparagraph{6}
\providecommand\theHsubsubparagraph {\theHsubparagraph.\arabic{subsubparagraph}}
\newcounter {subsubparagraph}[subparagraph]
\renewcommand\thesubsubparagraph {\thesubparagraph.\@arabic\c@subsubparagraph}
\newcommand*\l@subsubparagraph{\@dottedtocline{6}{12em}{6em}}
\newcommand\subsubparagraph{\@startsection{subsubparagraph}{6}{\parindent}%
                                       {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex}%
                                       {-1em}%
                                      {\normalfont\normalsize\itshape}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{enumitem}
\renewlist{itemize}{itemize}{9}
\setlist[itemize]{noitemsep, topsep=0pt}
\setlist[itemize,1]{label=\textbullet}
\setlist[itemize,2]{label=\textendash}
\setlist[itemize,3]{label=*}
\setlist[itemize,4]{label=·}
\setlist[itemize,5]{label =}

\usepackage[bidi=basic, layout=lists. tabular]{babel}
\babelfont[english]{rm}{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}%

\begin{itemize}
  \item Such subject is:
\begin{itemize}
  \item rigid-bo:
\begin{itemize}
  \item mics:
\begin{itemize}
 \item forces:
  \item bodies:
\begin{itemize}
 \item errer:
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the addition of more levels through the use of easlist package, I came across the answer posted by u/Zephyron51 in r/latex
https://www.reddit.com/r/LaTeX/comments/3dgcm5/easylist_levels_not_going_past_4/
Source code can be found in
https://pastebin.com/bNqEUrvx

The code can be modified as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,margin=2.5cm,bindingoffset=0.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{indentfirst} 
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} 
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{6} 

\makeatletter 
\def\toclevel@subsubparagraph{6}
\providecommand\theHsubsubparagraph {\theHsubparagraph.\arabic{subsubparagraph}}
\newcounter {subsubparagraph}[subparagraph]
\renewcommand\thesubsubparagraph {\thesubparagraph.\@arabic\c@subsubparagraph}
\newcommand*\l@subsubparagraph{\@dottedtocline{6}{12em}{6em}}
\newcommand\subsubparagraph{\@startsection{subsubparagraph}{6}{\parindent}%
                                       {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex}%
                                       {-1em}%
                                      {\normalfont\normalsize\itshape}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{enumitem}
\renewlist{itemize}{itemize}{9}
\setlistdepth{9}
\setlist[itemize]{noitemsep, topsep=0pt}
\setlist[itemize,1]{label=\textbullet}
\setlist[itemize,2]{label=\textendash}
\setlist[itemize,3]{label=*}
\setlist[itemize,4]{label=·}
\setlist[itemize,5]{label =}


\usepackage[at]{easylist} 
        \ListProperties(
                Progressive*=3ex,
                Space=5pt,
                Space*=5pt,
                Style1*=\textbullet\ \ ,
                Style2*=\begin{normalfont}\begin{bfseries}\textendash\end{bfseries}\end{normalfont} \ \ ,
                Style3*=\textasteriskcentered\ \ ,
                Style4*=\textperiodcentered\ \ ,
                Style5*=\textbullet\ \ ,
                Style6*=\begin{normalfont}\begin{bfseries}\textendash\end{bfseries}\end{normalfont}\ \ ,
                Style7*=\textasteriskcentered\ \ ,
                Style8*=\textperiodcentered\ \ ,
                Hide1=1,
                Hide2=2,
                Hide3=3,
                Hide4=4,
                Hide5=5,
                Hide6=6,
                Hide7=7,
                Hide8=8 )
                
                
\usepackage[bidi=basic,layout=lists.tabular]{babel}
\babelfont[english]{rm}{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}
 
 \begin{easylist}
\ListProperties(Space1=0.1cm, % Level not 1, Space1,  Level 1
                Space1*=0.1cm,% Level 1,     Space1*, Level 1
                Space2=0.15cm,    % Level not 2, Space2,  Level 2
                Space2*=0.1cm, % Level 2,     Space2*, Level 2
                Space3=0.1cm, % Level not 3, Space3,  Level 3
                Space3*=0.1cm, % Level 3,     Space3*, Level 3
                )
@ Such subject is:
@@ rigid-bo:
   @@@ mics: 
   @@@@  bodies:
   @@@@@  forces:
    @@@@@@ errer:
    @@@@@@@ errer:
    @@@@@@@@ errer: 
\end{easylist}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]